# Printing Data on dialog

Tags: c++, mfc

I need to display some data on my Dialog (Using MFC , Visual C++ 2010)

What is the easiest way to use `std::cout` and `std::setw` on a dialog box?

I have found some ways for `cout` (not sure if they will work or not) but nothing for `setw` ...

Thanks

Comment: Add a label. And assign the value to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use std::stringstream in substitution for cout.

```
std::stringstream out;
out << std::setw(5) << 100 << std::endl;
// and display out.str() in dialog box
```